# What do rb_yield_splat and rb_yield_values2 in C Ruby (MRI) do?

Tags: c, ruby

I see that Ruby has, in addition to the documented non-static functions `rb_yield` and `rb_yield_values` a couple of others that lack meaningful comments (and also aren't static). These are:

- `rb_yield_values2`: http://rxr.whitequark.org/mri/source/vm_eval.c#974
- `rb_yield_splat`: http://rxr.whitequark.org/mri/source/vm_eval.c#980

How does `rb_yield_values` differ from `rb_yield_values2`?

And `rb_yield_splat` looks like it takes an `Array` as an argument. When I use this, it seems to treat the array as with the `*` operator in Ruby, e.g., `yield(*params)`. Is this correct?

I can't find documentation anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, the interesting part of the answer where is `rb_yield_splat`, which allows us to treat arrays as parameters, as when we do `*params`.

For example, let's say we have some kind of special method that may work like this:

```
x.special_method do |x,y,z|
  # do whatever with x, y, and z
end
```

or like this:

```
x.special_method do |x,y|
  # do whatever, but this time only with x and y
end
```

The number of arguments to the yield may vary depending upon the properties of `x` (or arguments passed to `special_method`. If we know how many arguments we're dealing with (`count`), we use `rb_yield_values(count, arg1, arg2, ..., argn)` as always. But if we don't, and they're stored in a Ruby array, we can just do `rb_yield_splat(ary)`. Then `ary` can be basically any length.

As for the last part of the question, what is `rb_yield_values2`, this is easy. Let's look at the definition:

```
VALUE rb_yield_values2(int argc, const VALUE *argv) {
  return rb_yield_0(argc, argv);
}
```

That's basically just Ruby's `yield` method, which takes any number of arguments.

And `rb_yield_values(int n, ...)` is the C version, so we can call from C with a number of arguments to be determined (I assume at compile-time; I've never used this C convention, and don't know what it's called to search for it).